# Pythonic optimization of per-pixel image processing

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am processing an image in Python where I need to calculate an image metric on "how much is happening on an image". Metric calculates stripes of non-0 values, calculates sum of values inside the stripes, and calculate sum of squares of these sums.

Naive implementation which is processing every pixel on an image is painfully slow (as expected). What is the best way to rewrite it in Pythonic way, ideally if it can utilize multiple CPU's under the hood?

```
merit = 0.0

for y in range(height):
    segment_sum = 0
    for x in range(width):
        if test_image[y,x]>0:
            segment_sum+=test_image[y,x]
        elif segment_sum>0:
            if(segment_sum>1000):merit+=segment_sum*segment_sum #Ignore short segments
            segment_sum = 0

return merit
```

Comment: You can compute the sum for every row or column of an image using np.sum().  If you need blocks of rows or columns, just reduce the image in one dimension using cv2.resize() using INTER_AREA interpolation

Comment: That sort of algorithm needs to avoid Python if it is to be fast, so not sure how Pythonic that would be. It's fairly simple iteration, so probably Cython might be a decent choice. Not sure if it's even worth multithreading it, unless the input is really large.

Comment: just use `numba`, and maybe add some spaces in your code, like between punctuation. parallel programming requires some awareness. that code mixes up a few concepts, at the very least "reduction" and thresholding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) speeds up the code significantly:

```py
from timeit import timeit

import numpy as np
from numba import njit


def get_merit(image):
    height, width = image.shape

    merit = 0.0

    for y in range(height):
        segment_sum = 0
        for x in range(width):
            if image[y, x] > 0:
                segment_sum += image[y, x]
            elif segment_sum > 0:
                if segment_sum > 1000:
                    merit += segment_sum * segment_sum  # Ignore short segments
                segment_sum = 0

    return merit


@njit
def get_merit_numba(image):
    height, width = image.shape

    merit = 0.0

    for y in range(height):
        segment_sum = 0
        for x in range(width):
            if image[y, x] > 0:
                segment_sum += image[y, x]
            elif segment_sum > 0:
                if segment_sum > 1000:
                    merit += segment_sum * segment_sum  # Ignore short segments
                segment_sum = 0

    return merit


np.random.seed(42)

image = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(1000, 1000), dtype=np.uint8)
assert get_merit(image) == get_merit_numba(image)

t1 = timeit("get_merit(image)", number=1, globals=globals())
t2 = timeit("get_merit_numba(image)", number=1, globals=globals())

print(f"Time normal = {t1}")
print(f"Time numba  = {t2}")
```

Prints on my machine AMD 5700x:

```
Time normal = 1.1393451909534633
Time numba  = 0.00026865419931709766
```

Comment: Yeah, speed improvement is shocking. From 203 seconds down to 0.267 :-) And then when enabling auto-parallelization down to 0.1148 (which is probably too fast to fully utilize all cores). This is way better than I anticipated, 2000x speed  boost with 1 LOC :-)